# Datatable filter wrong space between header column and filter

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I'm developing an webpage with Primefaces + JSF. I did an **filter** on `dataTable` with `p:selectCheckboxMenu`, but appears between filter and header column some white-space, I've tried to remove it, but no success. 
My filter is using a custom object with custom, if I use `p:selectOneMenu` spaces not appears.

Someone could help me, please?

Page inspector image
[image]

My filter code:

```
                <p:column id="columnEmployeePost" filterBy="#{profile.employeePost}"
                filterMatchMode="in" filterStyle="white-space: normal;"
                headerText="#{language['language.datatable.profile.employeePost']}" style="white-space: normal;">                               
                <f:facet name="filter">
                    <p:selectCheckboxMenu id="employeeFilter" value="#{employeePost}"
                        onchange="PF('datatableVar').filter()"
                        converter="employeeConverterFilter"                         
                        label="#{language['language.datatable.profile.employeePost']}"
                        style="width: 100px; display: inherit; margin: 0 auto;" showHeader="true">                          
                        <f:selectItems
                            value="#{profileController.employeePosts}" var="selectEmployee"
                            itemLabel="#{selectEmployee.description}"
                            itemValue="#{selectEmployee}" itemLabelEscaped="true"/>
                    </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{profile.employeePost.title}" style="white-space: normal;"/>
            </p:column>
```

Comment: These `&nbsp;` are outside the `p:selectCheckboxMenu` so they most likely are somewhere in your xhtml

Comment: @Kukeltje I've already checked my form about some clue of it. Do you know if can be related with **tableStyle**? My tableSytle is "table-layout: auto"

Comment: Table-layout auto does not 'invent' `&nbsp;` chars... so no. What if you client-side remove them... experiment more